# Convert dataframe to time series

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a way to convert dataframe to time series (same like `mdeaths`)

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 
2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 
2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021), mon_day = c("January", 
"January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "March", 
"April", "April", "May", "May", "June", "June", "July", "July", 
"August", "August", "September", "September", "October", "October", 
"November", "November", "December", "December"), `R` = c(-427, 
-389, 18, -357, -230, -383, -259, -1233, -232, -875, -190, -489, 
-299, -448, -577, -662, -762, -552, -621, -488, -409, -290, -76, 
-155, -10)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022), .rows = structure(list(c(3L, 
    6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L), c(1L, 4L, 
    7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L), c(2L, 5L
    )), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

expected output

```
df1_ts  
       Jan    Feb   Mar
2020   --     --    --
2021   --     --    --
2022   --     --    --
```

It should be a timeseries data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do

```
dates <- with(df1, as.Date(paste(Year, mon_day, 1), "%Y %B %d"))
df2 <- df1[order(dates),]
ts1 <- ts(df2$R, start = c(df2$Year[1], match(df2$mon_day[1], month.name)), 
      frequency = 12)
ts1
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2020          18  -383 -1233  -875  -489  -448  -662  -552  -488  -290  -155
2021  -427  -357  -259  -232  -190  -299  -577  -762  -621  -409   -76   -10
2022  -389  -230

> str(ts1)
 Time-Series [1:25] from 2020 to 2022: 18 -383 -1233 -875 -489 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Convert to wide format and sort by Year. Then convert to time_series.

```
df_ts = df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(Year,names_from=mon_day,values_from=R) %>%
  arrange(Year)
df_ts = ts(df_wide[,-1], start=df_wide[1,1], end=df_wide[nrow(df_wide),1])
```

Output:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2020 
End = 2022 
Frequency = 1 
     January February March April  May June July August September October November December
2020      NA       18  -383 -1233 -875 -489 -448   -662      -552    -488     -290     -155
2021    -427     -357  -259  -232 -190 -299 -577   -762      -621    -409      -76      -10
2022    -389     -230    NA    NA   NA   NA   NA     NA        NA      NA       NA       NA
```

Class:

```
class(df_ts)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
      mutate(mon_day = factor(mon_day,
                              levels =c("January", "February",  "March",  
                              "April", "May",  "June",  "July", 
                              "August",  "September", "October", 
                              "November", "December")))%>%
      spread(mon_day, R) %>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Nope. But still its class is returning as ````[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"````. Where as the ````class(mdeaths)```` is ````ts````